# Vanilla JS check if remote image exists, else use fallback?

Tags: javascript, image

How can  var source be checked if it exists, and if not, be replaced by a local image I have on the server, e.g "/images/default.jpg"?

```
( function() {
            var youtube = document.querySelectorAll( ".youtube" );
                for (var i = 0; i < youtube.length; i++)
                {
                    var source = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ youtube[i].dataset.embed +"/sddefault.jpg";
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.src = source;

                    image.addEventListener( "load", function() {
                        youtube[ i ].appendChild( image );
                    }( i ) );

                    youtube[i].addEventListener( "click", function() {
                        var iframe = document.createElement( "iframe" );
                                iframe.setAttribute( "frameborder", "0" );
                                iframe.setAttribute( "allowfullscreen", "" );
                                iframe.setAttribute( "src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+ this.dataset.embed +"?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1" );
                                this.innerHTML = "";
                                this.appendChild( iframe );
                    } );    
                };
        } )();
```

Comment: You could use an onerror event for the Image object.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, if you use `onError` event for handling missing image `src`

```html
 <img src="main_img.png" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTDnT0jIkNanmzaS2TOjWqrH5zrqujijvxq1v2slPomCcquR9MSVg'" />
```

So, if your required image not exits then it will be replaced by a default image  e.g "/images/default.jpg", so in your case replace this `this.src` attribute like this `this.src="/images/default.jpg"`

Comment: I tried this yesterday with no luck. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @stavasknall have you try *Run code snippet* button here on SO?. you can see that `main_img.png` is missing thats why my default active image is showing after running the code.

Comment: Yes, I even tried implement the code on my server. The problem seems to be that Youtube spits out a 404 but at the same time uses it own fallback, see above answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers support an onerror event handler.

Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement

Something like this might help you?

```
var image = new Image();
image.onerror = function(e) {
    debugger;
    console.log("Change image src here?");
    this.src = "https://images.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";}
image.src = source;
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried the last one but it does not fire when var source not exists (404 in Chrome debugger console).

Comment: does changing `image.addEventListener('load', fn)` to `image.onload = fn` help?

Comment: Sorry, no. Could it be that youtube uses fallback by themselves (but still sends 404). Example: https://img.youtube.com/vi/qIZfstQJapw/sddefault.jpg

Comment: Ah! Now I see what you mean. The image's `load` event handler gets triggered but is still a 404. Sorry I couldn't help. Will reply if I find a way.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the complete and naturalWidth of the image:
https://stereochro.me/ideas/detecting-broken-images-js